# How can I prevent unsigned Git commits from being pushed to the repository?

Tags: git, digital-signature, gnupg

I'm collaborating on a project that has a requirement for GPG-signing all the commits.

Unfortunately, a Git GUI client I'm using together with the `git` CLI interface doesn't support GPG signing. I know how to easily [sign commits after the fact](https://superuser.com/a/1123928), so it's not a big deal.

But I have to *remember* to do that. In consequence, I'm sometimes accidentally pushing unsigned commits. Is there any way to easily prevent that from the client side?

Answer (score 1):

This can be easily done per repository, using the Git `pre-push` hook.

Create an **executable** text file located at `.git/hooks/pre-push` with the following content:

```bash
#!/bin/sh

while read local_ref local_sha remote_ref remote_sha
do
  for commit in $(git rev-list --reverse $remote_sha..$local_sha)
  do
    if ! git verify-commit $commit >/dev/null 2>&1
    then
      echo "ERROR: Unsigned commit detected!"
      exit 1
    fi
  done
done
```

When you attempt to accidentally push unsigned commits, the push will be prevented:

```bash
➜  App git:(feature-1) git push
ERROR: Unsigned commit detected!
error: failed to push some refs to 'github.com:cubuspl42/myrepo.git'
```

Note that hooks are not cloned, pushed, or pulled with the other code. If your co-workers or collaborators want to use this hook (or any other hook) then they'll need to add it themselves.

This solution is good when you have no strict control over the repository and would like to control your own actions. If you're the actual owner of the repository and want to **protect it** from accepting unsigned commits, you should **find another solution**.

Comment: Note that hooks are not cloned, pushed, or pulled with the other code - so if your co-workers or collaborators want to use this hook (or any other hook) then they'll need to add it themselves.

Comment: @JimRedmond I included this inside the answer, as it's a very good point